# Before start of resultset exeception in java jdbc exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset, sqlexception

```
try {
    String sql ="select * from staff where id=? ";

    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1,txt_search.getText());
    rs=pst.executeQuery();

    String add1 =rs.getString("id");
    txt_empid.setText(add1);

    String add2 =rs.getString("Name");
    txt_firstname.setText(add2);

    String add5 =rs.getString("Salary");
    txt_salary.setText(add5);

}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

here I have some problem in setString method. Can you please explain the reason for this error. I try lot of ways is this a problem of jdbc

Comment: Can you add the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException Before start of result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) as an iterator to the returned data. To access any row in the returned data, including the first, you need to advance the cursor to it by calling [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--). Or, as the documentation eloquently puts it (I added an **emphasize in bold** to the relevant sentence):

> A `ResultSet` object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. **Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row**. The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns `false` when there are no more rows in the `ResultSet` object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.)

To make a long story short - call `rs.next()` after you execute the query to advance it to the first (and only) row:

```
rs = pst.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
    String add1 = rs.getString("id");
    txt_empid.setText(add1);

    String add2 = rs.getString("Name");
    txt_firstname.setText(add2);

    String add5 = rs.getString("Salary");
    txt_salary.setText(add5);
} else {
    // The query returned no rows - i.e., the given ID doesn't exist in the table.
    // Some error handling is required here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mureinik It work so efficiently